Is it possible to solve this problem if the starting array position and size is random?
| |1|2|3|4|5|6|
Six of seven positions are occupied by six frogs, which are numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 as shown. A frog can jump to an adjacent position if it is vacant, or leap over another frog to the next position but one if it is vacant, and can move backwards or forwards. What is the least possible number of moves required if the frogs are to occupy the six positions which are occupied at the start, but in the order 6 5 4 3 2 1 reading from left to right?
to represent the empty cell use 0. so for example: the start array in the picture is
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

and the goal is
[0, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

the starting position and size is random so it can be like:
[2, 3, 1, 6, 4, 7, 0, 5]

i've found the solution if the starting position is not random and the size is even.
my solution:
n = int(input("How many frog: "))
sum = 0

arr = [0 for i in range(n+1)]

for i in range(n+1):
    arr[i] = i

# even
if n % 2 == 0:
    for j in range(n//2):
        for i in range (0, n, 2):
            arr[i], arr[i+2] = arr[i+2], arr[i]
            sum += 1
            print (sum, ":", arr)

        arr[n-1], arr[n] = arr[n], arr[n-1]
        sum+=1
        print (sum, ":", arr)

        for i in range(n-1, 1, -2):
            arr[i], arr[i-2] = arr[i-2], arr[i]
            sum += 1
            print (sum, ":", arr)
        
        arr[0], arr[1] = arr[1], arr[0]
        sum+=1
        print (sum, ":", arr)



Copy & paste the original problem as text instead of images.

this is kind of like bubble sort only with jumping over one place in the array right?

Post your code, along with a specific question about what's giving you trouble.

sorry i've added the problem in text

this is kind of like bubble sort only with jumping over one place in the array right?
yes jumping over one number or just switch if the 0 is right beside it

Post your code, along with a specific question about what's giving you trouble.
i've added my solution, sorry im new on this kinda stuff

We are not people who do your homework for you for free. Get to work.
not exactly my homework, its just i've kinda took interest on this problem

The answer to your first question.  Yes, this is always a solution.  And since there is a solution, there must be a minimum one.
Suppose you have A B C D E F G 0 and you want to swap the A and B.  You move the '0' down by switching it with the next element until you have  A B 0 C D E F G.  You then leapfrog and have 0 B A C D E F G`.
Since you can swap any two adjacent elements, you can do a bubble sort.  That means every position can be solved.
